# Why does OpenStreetMap give a 403 error through Python's urllib.request.urlretrieve, but works perfectly when using Requests?

Tags: python, http, http-headers, user-agent

I'm trying to grab tiles from OpenStreetMap. I learned the syntax of their API. I have an "old way" of doing things, using Requests, and a "new way", which is being used by someone else's github project. I'm trying to use their project, but it's failing for me in one spot. I then put together this short script as a minimal example:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
import urllib.request

#A tile we want to grab from Open Street Map
tile_url = "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/16/19299/24629.png"


#Old way: Get the bytes via requests.get, then parse as image and save.
old_way = Image.open(requests.get(tile_url,stream=True).raw)
old_way.save("oldway.png")


#New way: use urlretrieve to directly copy the file over to newway.png
destination = "newway.png"
try:
    path, response = urllib.request.urlretrieve(tile_url, destination)
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print("URL error!")
    print(e.code)

#Expected behavior: Two identical images are created,
#named oldway.png and newway.png
#Actual behavior: We get oldway, but newway gives a 403 error.
```

What's going wrong here? What's the difference between these two HTTP GET requests which results in the first one working fine, and the second one giving a 403 error? I've tried digging into the source code of the respective Python libraries, but it turns out to be a pretty long mess of functions calling each other. And of course since it's HTTPS, I can't monitor the network connection to evaluate the raw bytes being transferred and figure things out that way.

Is there something wrong with the user-agent? Something with the headers? Please note that I'm not just trying to solve this problem ("What's the issue? You have a method that works. Ignore the broken one"), but I'm trying to learn about the details here and hoping that this odd edge case can benefit me in the future.